# Magento redirect to login page while user not login on landing

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I want to redirect the user to login page on landing, While user is not logged in.

for example :-

```
example.com ->(not logged in)-> redirect to login page.

example.com ->(logged in)-> redirect to Home page.
```

How can i do this ?

I was found some function like this

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    parent::preDispatch();

    if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this)) {
        $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
    }
}
```

How can i use or where should i use this.

Hope some will have experience on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: try this link, free extension [Custom Login Redirect](http://www.magepsycho.com/shop/free-stuffs/custom-login-redirect.html)

Comment: and this is another site [Redirect not-logged customers](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-redirect-customer-to-login-page-if-not-logged-in/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This one save is me,

```
if(!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){

  Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));

}
```

And i called it in cms page block.Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 2):

```
$customerId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$customer   = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                  ->load($customerId);

$userSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$userSession->setCustomer($customer);
Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));

$this->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
```

Hope this help

Comment: :Thanks for the code, but where should i add the code in template.

Comment: you can create a phtml file and put it in your template, add it to your homepage cms by use
{{block type="core/template" name="redirect_block" template="your_template/your_phtml.phtml"}}

Answer (score 1):

```
$redirect_url = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login/');
$current_url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
if((!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) && ($current_url != $redirect_url)){
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirect_url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

below code works for me Magento 2

```
<?php
namespace BA\BasysGiftCertificate\Controller\CustAccount;
 
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index implements \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirect;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirect
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        RedirectFactory $resultRedirect,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->resultRedirect = $resultRedirect;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
    /**
     * Default customer account page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login');
            return $resultRedirect;
        } else {
            return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        }
    }
}
```